# iPad UIViewController subview reset issues

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview

I am not really sure how to phrase this question but to keep it simple;
I originally started my app for iPhone but now made it universal. Being that did that, I started making iPad.xib files as well... Everything is complete now and everything is working how it should except ONE thing...

On the Controllers, I have an instructions button, (button that when touched, a uiview gets added to the center of the screen and says the instructions).

That all works great but for some reason when I touch it on one of the new iPad Controller (from the iPad xib) all the buttons that were moved around the view prior to touching the button, start to revert back to the initial position...

I do have a function that makes them do that, but to my knowledge, it is not being activated when this instructions button gets touched. If it were, I'm sure this "error" would also happen in the iPhone simulator...

Anyone have any idea? I keep looking at different solutions but can't really figure this out.

Thanks!!

Comment: Use breakpoints and try to figure out if the code to move the elements back is being called. We can't perform debugging without seeing code, though, so you should post some.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be calling anything but the "showInstructions" function when I touch the instructions button...

Comment: data provided is insufficient. You don't know whats going on and you expect us to tell you.. ??

Comment: No, I do not expect you to have a direct answer for my question. Like I have stated, I do not really know how to ask this question. I am just looking for some ideas that anyone might have I might be able to try out. The debugging idea was something I didn't realize to try. But no luck

Comment: This is most likely due to auto layout. If you change the frame of a view by setting frames, when the view updates (for any reason), the views will revert to the frames that are determined by their constraints. To fix the problem, you should move your buttons around using constraints, or turn off auto layout.

Comment: You sir are a genius! Getting rid of autolayout worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: @rdelmar You should post this as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to auto layout. If you change the frame of a view by setting frames, when the view updates (for any reason), the views will revert to the frames that are determined by their constraints. To fix the problem, you should move your buttons around using constraints, or turn off auto layout. While turning off auto layout is the easy way to fix this, you really should learn how to use that system.

Comment: I figured I can just turn it off for this case being that the buttons that are being messed up are moveable buttons by the user during runtime. But yea, eventually I should learn how to use autolayout + constraints.